# Java writing to files from a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java program that writes to a file whenever a user does a certain action. To avoid blocking the main thread I thought it would be best to handle writing to that file on a separate thread. Anyways I am wondering what's the best way to go about that. At first I created a new object that implements Runnable. Then when ever I needed to write to a file I created a new instance of that object and a new thread, passed in the runnable as a parameter to the thread and started it. This works fine however I was not sure if this was the best approach and based on my research apparently creating a new thread object is very memory intensive.

```
            final UpdateConfigRunnable runnable = new UpdateConfigRunnable(stringData, object);
            final Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
```

Normally I was passing in an object (all data being queried from that object is final) and some string data into the constructor of my runnable object. One issue is I cant generate a new runnable and pass it into the same thread which means I need to make the thread once and the runnable once then maybe update stringData with a setter method before I call the start method? That implantation would look like this.

```
public class NormalClass {
final UpdateConfigRunnable runnable;
final Thread thread;

public NormalClass(Object object) {
    runnable = new UpdateConfigRunnable(object);
    this.thread = new Thread(runnable);
}

public void updateFile(String data) {
    runnable.setData(data);
    thread.start();
}
}
```

In the above implementation "NormalClass" is only ever accessed / called by one single thread. Calling the updateFile() method would then change the value of stringData inside the runnable object before I start the thread with the start() method. Is this the second example the correct way to go about this if not what did I get wrong about using multiple threads in this scenario?

Edit:
Let me know if the following implementation of blocking queue is correct.

```
public class UpdateConfigRunnable implements Runnable {
private final BlockingQueue<ScreenGui> blockingQueue;

public UpdateConfigRunnable(final BlockingQueue<ScreenGui> blockingQueue) {
    this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            final ScreenGui screenGui = blockingQueue.take();

            final int sizeOfFont = screenGui.getSizeOfFont();
            final String font = screenGui.getFontName();

           //I will handle writing to the file here

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Now here is the class which will be adding to queue. Here you can see I am actually adding a reference of this ScreenGui since that contains an object which I need to reference in order to obtain 2 final variables. Then I also need to pass in an this's instance of ScreenGui since in order for the runnable to have access sizeOfFont and fontName which I marked volatile since I want to keep those variables in ram to avoid compiler optimization (the values may be updated in cache but not in ram when viewed from the other thread). I could instead of passing in ScreenGui make a separate object which contains everything I need but I am not sure if generating a new object just for that is more optimized than just saving a larger object in memory aka ScreenGui.

```
final BlockingQueue<ScreenGui> blockingQueue;
final UpdateConfigRunnable runnable;
final Thread fileSaverThread;

private volatile String fontName;
private volatile int sizeOfFont;

public ScreenGui() {
    this.blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    this.runnable = new UpdateConfigRunnable(blockingQueue);
    this.fileSaverThread = new Thread(runnable);
    fileSaverThread.setDaemon(true);
    fileSaverThread.start();
}

public void saveFile() {
    try {
        blockingQueue.put(this);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also since the thread is a daemon thread I assume making an infinite while loop is fine inside of the runnable.

Comment: That would create a new thread for each message to be stored. Apart from threads not being cheap, how to ensure only one thread at a time would write to the file?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Wait so calling the start method will create a new thread each time despite the thread and runnable object only being initialized once? I know the run method is used only when that thread is already running. I thought that after the thread finishes running the code in the start() it will auto stop the thread but keep it initialized so that calling start() again in the future will use the same thread but start it again. I assume with blocking queue it keeps the thread running in sleep mode instead of starting it again is this faster?

Comment: But yes you are right I would have no way of ensuring the file is only written to once (I overlooked that so thanks for bringing that up). I could use synchronization but a blocking queue at the moment appears to be the better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one thread that keeps reading from a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and writing to the file. If there is nothing in the queue, the thread gets blocked by the BlockingQueue.take() method.

Now all your other threads have to do is to add data via the BlockingQueue.add() method.

Example:

```
public class ScreenGui {
    // contains the data that shall get written to the file
    // note that this class is a dumb data object - it does not create
    // any queues, threads or whatsoever
}

/** The FileWriter Thread. Shall be a singleton.
  */
public class Filer {
    private BlockingQueue<ScreenGui> bq;
    private Thread thread;

    private static Filer instance;
    private Filer() {
        bq = new BlockingQueue<>();
        thread = new Thread(()->{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...);
            while(true) {
                ScreenGui data = bq.take();
                
                // somehow write the ScreenGui to the output stream
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    private static synchronized Filer getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Filer();
        }
    }
    public void write(ScreenGui data) {
        bq.put(data);
    }
}

/** The class that contains the actual application. It generates
  * the data that shall end up in the file.
  */
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Filer filer = Filer.getInstance();  // with this the filer is initialized, it has a BlockingQueue and the background thread is waiting to write data

        // now either use this thread or more to write data
        filer.write(new ScreenGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not used a BlockingQueue before but it sounds like a good solution so I am reading a bunch on it so I will let you know if I have any questions if not and it sounds good ill accept your answer.

Comment: The API documentation contains example code, you'd just need to fill in your payload (write to file and create the data chunks to be written)

Comment: Alright Hiran I updated my initial question with my blocking queue implementation can you let me know if it looks good? If you think it's the best way of doing it ill accept your answer.

Comment: It seems like ScreenGui is the data entity you want to send to the file. Why do you create one fileSaverThread for each data entity? Having one of them in total should be enough. I edit my answer.

Comment: What do you mean I am only creating one thread and saving it in ScreenGui. Only one ScreenGui object will ever be made so I am not understanding what the issue is.

Comment: You created the BlockingQueue<ScreenGui> so I assume the ScreenGui is the data you want to write. If that assumption is wrong, just rename the class.

Comment: Yes I wanted to write data inside of ScreenGui.

Comment: What is the major difference between your approach and my approach using blockingQueue?

Answer (score -1):

Juste replace old thread with a new Thread inside updateFile and for each call, interrupt and cancel all changes of the old thread and replace it with a new one, with previous data that you canceled, to save it in the file with the new data you want to store for the current function call

**I did a small implementation :**

```
import java.io.*;


public class HelloWorld  {

    public volatile String oldFileData = "";
    private  Thread activeThread ;


    public HelloWorld(String init) {
        //inside the constructor read all the current file content iven if it's blocking because it will be done once and will be usefull for ever
        this.oldFileData = init;
    }

    public void updateLogFile(String toPrint){
        if(activeThread!=null && activeThread.isAlive()) {
            activeThread.interrupt();
            //replace all content in write mode
            this.activeThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    // replace all in that file with oldFileData
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                            new FileWriter("log.txt") // without true for write mode 
                    );
                    out.println(oldFileData + toPrint);//replace all
                    out.close();
                    oldFileData += toPrint;//if no exception this means the job is done and oldFileData must be updated
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            activeThread.start();
        }else{
            //add to previous data
            this.activeThread = new Thread(() -> {
                // open file in append mode to add and not replace
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                            new FileWriter("log.txt",true ) //USE TRUE FOR APPEND
                    );
                    out.println(toPrint);
                    out.close();
                    oldFileData += toPrint;//if no exception this means the job is done and oldFileData must be updated
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            activeThread.start();
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld("I m old content from the file");
        hw.updateLogFile("User clicked button1 \n");
        hw.updateLogFile("User clicked button2 ");

        System.out.println(hw.oldFileData);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this better than the blockingque solution? Wouldn't assigning a new thread each time be the same as what I originally had since it would need to spend the over head crafting a new thread object each time I try to write to a file?

Comment: When you detect an active thread, which means a write operation to the file is ongoing - why do you interrupt it? BTW, you are not writing a file at all.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Very disappointed by your comment. it's clear that i didn't because it's only an example ... Also i interupt the thread because new text must be stored while while last text didn't finish .

Comment: What happens when part of the data have already been written but not everything so it is still in progress and you interrupt the thread because new data has arrived?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri With the above implementation wont it be creating a new thread object each time it writes to a file meaning it carries more memory overhead than using the same thread object and just restarting it each time you need to write to a file? Obviously, the blocking queue seems like a better solution but is my analysis correct?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri  that is the main reason why i check if thread is alive or not to do `out.println(oldFileData + toPrint);` and truncate the file then rewriting everything